# i want to get new lin for each node xml when i use descendants() method

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I use descendants method to get each node attributes in new line individually. how i can do that. i use code below ,but by this code, i get all attributes in one line.

```
var txml:XML;
var xmlloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlloader.load(new URLRequest("‫‫olwantree.xml"));
xmlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaded);
function loaded(e:Event):void
{   txml = new XML(xmlloader.data);
       for each (var newxml:XML in txml){
       var str:String = newxml.descendants().attributes().toString();
      str += "\n";
    trace(str);

    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to do something like this:

```
var str:String;

for each (var newxml:XML in e.xml)
{
    for each (var d:XML in newxml.descendants())
    {
        for each (var a:XML in d.attributes())
        {
            str = a.toString();
            str += "\n";
            trace(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you use `toString()`. And you don't need that loop - this will work much faster:

```
var attributes:XMLList = txml.descendants().attributes();

for (var i:uint = 0; i < attributes.length(); i++)
{
    trace (attributes[i].name()); // gives name
    trace (attributes[i].name()); // gives value

    // I don't understand if you store them in a string or something
    // but you can do any manipulation here
    // it's for each attribute on each child of the root
}
```